# Is there any difference between racing driver and formula 1 driver?

Tags: formula-1, auto-racing

I want to know if is there any difference between a racing car driver and a formula one driver?

Have a look at the 2 images I have attached, both from Google.

Against the name of Massa there is formula 1 driver is written whereas racing driver is shown against Jules Bianchi.

So this was my doubt as if there is any difference between formula one driver or racing driver?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "racing car driver"?

Comment: What are you even asking? There is difference between every Formula One drive. As a matter of fact between every human being. If you are asking whats the difference between Formula One "driving" & other race car "driving" than thats a different matter

Comment: Voting to close as unclear until some clarification is supplied.

Comment: The edit helps, but this is still off-topic as you're asking "What algorithm does Google use to determine the tag line for a person?" and that's nothing to do with sports per se.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Google's algorithms.

Answer (score 5):

Those details from google are literally a collection of information that it pulls from various websites in which a user adds the information to describe them.

Example: Angelo is a gun-owner. The gun he owns is a .238 Summerfield Winchester. One site might put him as a "Gun-owner". This is equivalent of **"racing driver"**. The other one might put him as a ".238 Summerfield Winchester" owner. This is the equivalent of **"Formula 1 driver"**.